# Iterating Keys with Fields on a given Type

Tags: scala, shapeless

I have a type defined:

```
case class Foo(bar: String)
```

For which I want to iterate over the fields (both the type and the name). So, I define a LabelledGeneric, and a Keys instance for that.

```
val labl = LabelledGeneric[Foo]
val keys = Keys[labl.Repr].apply
```

Now I can't make a Fields without an instance of `Foo`. Is there some other way of getting the field type information without an instance of the case class? All the examples I have seen so far use an instance of the type in question, but I don't have an instance, just the type. Ideal would be some `(Key,Field)` collection.

*Edit: Previous version of question was trying to use poly1 on the Keys but I realized the Keys don't have the type information.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fields extends DepFn1 and hence requires one argument in its apply method.

However you can adapt its definition to collect the ClassTags of your Repr:

```
trait FieldTags[L <: HList] extends DepFn0 with Serializable {
  type Out = List[(Symbol, ClassTag[_])]
}

object FieldTags {
  def apply[L <: HList](implicit fields: FieldTags[L]): FieldTags[L] = fields

  implicit def hnilFields[L <: HNil]: FieldTags[L] = 
    new FieldTags[L] { def apply() = List.empty }

  implicit def hconsFields[K <: Symbol, V, T <: HList](implicit
                                                    key: Witness.Aux[K],
                                                    tailFields: FieldTags[T],
                                                    tag: ClassTag[V])
  : FieldTags[FieldType[K, V] :: T] = new FieldTags[FieldType[K, V] :: T] {
    def apply() = (key.value -> tag) :: tailFields.apply()
  }
}

val fields: List[(Symbol, ClassTag[_])] = FieldTags[labl.Repr].apply()
println(fields)
// List(('br, java.lang.String))
```

Comment: What's the definition of FieldTags ?

Comment: Thanks for adding. I'll test the solution and let you know.